# ReferenceError trying to access closure variable inside await callback in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, closures

(I looked through similar questions and could not find an answer for my problem, so asking here.)

Why is the code below giving me the error "ReferenceError: myText is not defined"?

```
    async myFunction(myText: string)
    {
        await this.asyncThing.evaluate(() => {
            console.log(myText);  // error is thrown here
        });
    }
```

Not sure why the closure should not still be active when the log function is called.   Is there a workaround for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using Puppeteer. Although the function you pass to `evaluate` looks like a regular closure, it is actually serialized and sent across the wire to the browser. This means that it doesn't actually close over/have access to the variables in the parent scope. Instead you must explicitly pass those variables as arguments to the `evaluate` function:

```
async myFunction(myText: string)
{
    await this.asyncThing.evaluate((myTextInBrowser) => {
        console.log(myTextInBrowser);
    }, myText); // <- pass the variable in here
}
```

This is not called out very well in the documentation, but it is under "Passing arguments to pageFunction:" https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args

Answer (score 1):

The variable isn't visible inside the closure because the closure has no argument.

Consider

```
await this.asyncThing.evaluate((myText) => {
    console.log(myText);
});
```